# Problem with PyInstaller and local packages

Tags: python, module, package, pyinstaller, hook

My project is structured as follows:

- `example3/`

  - `window/`

    - `__init__.py`
    - ...
  - `__init__.py`
  - `__main__.py`
- `setup.py`
- `example.py`

in the main file:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
import window

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = window.Main()
    main_window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The build script example.py for PyInstaller:

```
from example3.__main__ import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How do I get PyInstaller to recognize my project's packages or the modules in them? PyInstaller only sees the packages installed using pip. I had read something about hook files but didn't really understand how to do it.

I created the executable with the command:

```
> pyinstaller example.py --onefile
```

When I try to run the application I get the error message:

```
> ./dist/example
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "example3/__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/tmp/embedded.xpuoquuw.zip/shibokensupport/__feature__.py", line 146, in _import
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'window'
[127129] Failed to execute script 'example' due to unhandled exception!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be solved by telling PyInstaller the search path for my project's modules and packages:

```
pyinstaller --onefile example.py --paths ./example3/
```